# Session expired in XCode 7.1 when trying to export application as Ad Hoc Deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, session

How to fix problem that picture below shows? My session has expired but my developers account is valid and all Provisioning Profiles are Active. Thank you for your answers and help.

[image: Session expired]

Comment: Please check your internet connection.

Comment: Internet connection work fine all the time.

Comment: ok then remove your developer account from preferences. and Add.  I hope it's working.

Comment: I did that to already and it didn't work.

Comment: There is one last chance which I have is quit your xcode restart your mac and and re-sign in to the errant account in Xcode > Preferences > Accounts. Because there is no technical issues from apple side today.

Comment: I did it... It works fine now. I removed all accounts from XCode for the fourth time and add only one that I work with.

Comment: Thanks for help... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try remove old developer account and agains long.

```
Xcode -> Preferences -> Account
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do **Two-factor Authentication** for your developer account .On your mobile

Go to setting->icloud->click on your account->password&Security->complete the two-Factor Authentication . [Click here](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204915) for more details